# Globally define maven project encoding

Tags: maven

I'm on windows a lot of the time and usually forget to do this so I'm constantly getting warnings about how my project encoding hasn't been set. Is there a way I can globally define this (maybe in settings.xml?) or not?

Comment: Not in settings. Pleys put it in a company pom and inherit from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try setting the encoding property in a profile that is activated in the settings:

```
<settings>
   [...]
   <profiles>
      <profile>
         <id>inject-project-encoding</id>
         <properties>
            <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
         </properties>
      </profile>
  </profiles>

  <activeProfiles>
      <activeProfile>inject-project-encoding</activeProfile>
  </activeProfiles>
</settings>
```

Comment: Is it possible to **only** define an OS family for profile activation? Given that I only need this on Windows systems, or will I have to define each Windows OS I use?

Comment: Don't do that. Best is to define such things in a company pom and inherit from there but not from settings. Cause everyone can have a different settings.xml on it's machine.

Comment: All the computers belong to me and I keep the settings.xml synced across my computers because of things like sonatype deployment settings, does that change anything?

Comment: @Albion See [this link](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html) for how to use and activate profiles.

Comment: I've looked at that. I asked if it was possible to **ONLY** define the OS family whereas Apache's examples define the entire OS.

Comment: I'm not sure but my guess is that it should work with only the OS family. You can give it a try.